# Mathematical sequence puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

Bob is trying to crack a puzzle. He finds this numerical sequence:

> 9056, 528, 64

What should he input after 64?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: have I done something wrong?? :'(

Comment: Here's a hint.... one gone.....twice...

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712). In short, there are really too many ways to get these numbers, so the puzzle is too open-ended.

Comment: I dont mean this in any disrespect, but I feel that this kind of puzzle is alright, when you can give hints in comment form when one does not get the answer correct. However, I thank you for your correction and will keep this in mind for future puzzles.

Comment: Another problem with this type of sequence puzzle is that with only 3 terms there are usually a LOT of different possible answers arithmetically. Plus plain mathematical sequences aren't especially exciting. The best sequence puzzles (in my opinion anyway) have some characteristic that makes it an *interesting* sequence, to set it apart from all the others that can be achieved through some arbitrary combination of mathematical operations. Take a look at the most upvoted puzzles within this tag to see what usually goes down well here :)

Comment: I tried to make it easy but fun sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original Answer:

> My guess: 22 
>  Going backwards starting from 64: 
>  528 = 64 * 2 + 400 
>  9056 = 528 * 2 + 8000 
>  Notice that 400 = 20^2 and 8000 = 20^3
>  Therefore, it looks like the pattern would be n * 2 + 20 = 64, so n = 22

Edit:

Going in the other direction as suggested in the comment, we notice that:

9056 / 2 = 4**528**

528 / 2 = 2**64**

So the pattern could also be dividing by 2 and removing the leading digit.

Using this approach we get

> 64 / 2 = 3**2** for a final answer of 2

Comment: not quite, try right to left.

Comment: AMAZING!!! Great job Kevin!

Answer (score 2):

> 7664

via polynomial interpolation

Comment: not quite, try simpler ways of solution.